How do I transfer the client's UI into server side?
How do I copy the client's UI into the server when the player leaves?
So how it is going to work is that when the player leaves, their UI will be saved onto the server side and when they join back, they will still have that UI. Except it doesn't work or I just don't know how to use datastore properly. I want only the main frame to save as it contains all of the other items parented to it. Is there a better way to save the frame only?

P.S. My knowledge on scripting is beginning to grow (still little though) so it would help out a lot if someone can explain what they do and how they work so I don't come across this question again. Thank you.

So you cannot save the UI, but you can save a representation of the UI, or just enough information so you can recreate the UI later. If you have a TextLabel that says, "you have 5 apples", you don't need to save the whole TextLabel, just that you have 5 apples, or maybe just the number 5. It might be worth taking some time to think about what values are worth saving, then look into how you can use DataStoreService to save and retrieve those values later.

@Kylaaa How so? How would I replicate the client sided value and transform it into a server side value? Are you able to further explain more?

There's not enough relevant information in your question for me to give you a meaningful answer. There is usually some underlying data that is displayed with your UI. If we use my previous example, if you have local appleCount = 5, then you might have your TextLabel display it with TextLabel.Text = string.format("You have %d apples", appleCount). The only thing that needs to be saved is appleCount. If appleCount exists on your client, you can use a RemoteEvent to send it up to the server to be saved. But I need more info

But realistically, that values stored on a client shouldn't be the "source of truth".  In many client-server arrangements, there is a common saying that you should  "never trust the client". If a client can tell the server, "please save my 5 apples for me", then the client can also tell the server "please save my 9 million apples for me".   So you should try to keep the data you want to save on the server. You can let the client display the number for you, but the server should be responsible for its true value.
